# Why does jQuery not work like CSS in terms of inheritance?

Tags: jquery, hierarchy

This should be so simple:

```
$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#00cc00"}, 'fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#939393"}, 'fast');
});

$(".footer_link").find("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#333"}, 'fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#939393"}, 'fast');
});
```

I'm telling my page to make all  tags on hover change colour.

Then i'm giving a different rule for  tags in a specific div.

I know if I do this in CSS, it will work. But in jQuery, the first rul overrides all rules.

It would be reallly cumbersome to find all the divs and spans that have  tags and specify them all just so i can have one single  tag do something different.

Am I doing something wrong here?

You can see it here: http://baked-beans.tv (the footer is where things are not working as they should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
$(".footer_link").find("a").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').hover(yourhoverfunctions)
```

By that you first unbind the hover bound to

```
.footer_link a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".footer_link").find("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#333"}, 'fast');
    $(this).stopPropagation();
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({color: "#939393"}, 'fast');
    $(this).stopPropagation();
});
```

Does this make a trick?
In jQuery you add events, not properties, so you end up with 2 events on 1 item, the above solution should execute the first event and `$(this).stopPropagation();`, stopping event propagation.
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/icexa4/edit)

The best solution in this case is not to register events on the elements twice and filter out `.footer_link` anchors in your first statement using [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: I edited my answer, changed `return false;` to `event.stopPropagation()` and added a demo.

Comment: `.stopPropagation()` is a method on the event object, not on a jQuery object.

Comment: I know that, but since hover handlers don't take event as a parameter I tried it anyway and it seems to work, you may see it yourself in the demo above, but yes, I agree, it is more of a hack.

Comment: Your method is having no effect, it's the fact that it's bound later that makes it work...the entire problem here is an incorrect selector in the OP's page.  Also the functions *do* take event as a parameters, they always have, `function(e) {` like every other event handler.   But it wouldn't matter anyway, since the handler is on the same element, there's no need to stop propagation, since there's no parent in play.

Comment: well try to uncomment the commented lines, and you will see yourself (at least it works in Firefox and Chrome). I was wrong about eventObject in hover functions though.

Answer (score 1):

It does *sort of* work like CSS in this case, since you're using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and binding later with the second (since the second will stop the first).

However, it at least *appears* to me that your selector is off, `class="footer_link"` doesn't appear anywhere, I *think* what you'are after is this instead:

```
$("#footer").find("a").hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({color: "#333"}, 'fast');
}, function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({color: "#939393"}, 'fast');
});
```

Note that this still isn't very efficient since you're binding 2 handlers for the same thing, it'd be better to not bind *all* `<a>` elements from the start.